# How to make a graphic window modal in scilab?

Tags: properties, dialog, modal-dialog, window, scilab

What property of the figure should be set to make it modal?
I want to prohibit user interaction with the main program window while my dialog window is open. But there does not seem to be a property for that.

Comment: How do you create your dialog window ? Please give a minimal example of code.

Comment: The function looks something like this  

    `function MFDlg()`  

       `f=figure('figure_position',[360,157],'figure_size',[500,150],'auto_resize','off','background',[33],'figure_name','Window' );`  

       `handles.dummy = 0;`  

       `// Create the uicontrols something like this  handles.MForm1=uicontrol(f,'unit',...`  

  
  
  
  
 `handles.BtnOK=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','BtnOK_callback(handles)');`  


       `f.visible = "on";`  

    `endfunction`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a figure modal by setting a figure's property. But if you want to block the access to the Scilab command line, at the end of the statements of your function you can use a waiting loop, such as

```
while %t
   if is_handle_valid(f)
      sleep(1)
   else
      break
   end
end
```

In the above example, the loop continues until the figure is closed, but you can make other tests, e.g. involving values set by callbacks.